# SQL Server: differences between "in" and "join" syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, inner-join

I thought the two SQL statements shown below are functionally the same, but obviously I was wrong because they return different results.

Can anyone explain?

```
select count(*) 
from t 
where t.id in (select distinct v_id from v)

select count(*) 
from t 
join v on t.id = v.v_id
```

Comment: The technical difference in terminology is that `IN` is a semi-join, it just returns a yes/no as to whether there is a match. By the way, the `distinct` is unnecessary, and a good optimizer will elide it.

Comment: You would understand that better by simply removing the counts, adding the primary key columns of all tables (really only need PK columns) to the select list, ordering appropriately, and then simply comparing the resultsets.

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN` can change the number of rows in a query in two ways:

1. When values do not match, then rows are filtered out.
2. When the tables have duplicates, then the result set has those duplicates.

`IN` filters out non-matching values.  However, it does not generate duplicates if `v` has duplicates.  If the results are different, it suggests that `v` has duplicates with respect to `v_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to explain in simple words.
First query will return count(*) from **t** if t.id is in table **v**

But second query will join both tables with id and v_id first. Then it will return count from their joined table.

For example if t has 1, 2 and 1 as id and v has 1 and 2 as id

```
select count(*) from t where t.id in (select distinct v_id from v)
and 
select count(*) from t join v on t.id = v.v_id
```

both query will return same result as count: 3

```
select count(*) from v where t.v_id in (select distinct id from t)
and 
select count(*) from t join v on t.id = v.v_id
```

will return different result. first query will return 2 but second query will return 3.

Join can increase the row count if there is duplicate values in tables.